# PIC 18F2550 USB Dual Power Example

Tags: pic, usb, diodes

In the PIC18F2550 datasheet, there is an example about how to dual Power it in the figure 17-12. I understand the whole circuit, I am just not sure why there is this diode after the Vself?

[image: The circuit for USB Dual Power]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it figured...If there is power on the Vbus, and there is no diode, the PNP transistor will shut off, since there will be a V+ in its base terminal, and then there will be no energy in the PNP, so it will turn on again, because this time the base terminal will receive a 0V level, and this way sending a V+ to the PNP again, turning it off again, making it into a cycle, causing an erratic behaviour...the capacitor will even make things go slower.